# Error 415 when uploading attachment to Confluence via REST API?

Tags: powershell, confluence-rest-api

I'm trying to upload a file as an attachment to a Confluence page via the REST API, but I keep getting error 415, which according to [this page](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-415-unsupported-media-type) means "Unsupported Media Type".

I have Confluence Server so I'm going off of [this example](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-rest-api-examples/#upload-an-attachment) in Confluence Server's REST API documentation. I've also looked at [this](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/rest/v1/api-group-content---attachments/#api-wiki-rest-api-content-id-child-attachment-post) from the Confluence Cloud documentation, but it looks basically the same.

Here's my code:

```
Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Method POST `
    -Uri https://<confluence server>/confluence/rest/api/content/<pageID>/child/attachment `
    -InFile file.txt `
    -Headers @{
        Authorization = "Basic <basicAuth>"
    }
```

I've found many of the same/similar questions and most of the answers are to set the correct Content Type. Many of the answers point to [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fishkb/rest-api-error-415-unsupported-media-type-313468261.html), which says the same.

I've tried all variations of content types and none of them work:

- application/json
- application/text
- text/plain
- application/xml
- multipart/form-data

Nothing is working. The only change happens if I set the content type to simply 'text', then I get a different error:

> HTTP Status 400 – Bad Requestbody

It's a plain text file, but ultimately I'll be uploading different file types like docx, etc. so hopefully the content type isn't filetype-specific.

Is there a content type I'd use for any general purpose file upload?

Also, many of the examples I've seen have "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" in the headers and I don't know what that does, but I tried including that as well. Not sure if I did it right:

```
Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Method POST `
    -Uri https://<confluence server>/confluence/rest/api/content/<pageID>/child/attachment `
    -InFile file.txt `
    -Headers @{
        Authorization = "Basic <basicAuth>"
        'X-Atlassian-Token' = 'nocheck'
    }
```

It still didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you replace the items inside angle brackets with real values? You need a server and pageID.  You also need an OAUTH2 token to make the connection.    Examples show you should be using "application/json".  An HTP request has three parts 1) URI 2) HTTP Headers 3) Body.  Make sure you are putting parameters in the json body and not as a header.  See : https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-rest-api-examples/#create-a-page-with-a-task

Comment: All HTTP requests are the same when transmitted.  Depending on the tool (like PS or python) you add the pieces (URI, headers, body) differently.  Some tools like PS will automatically count bytes in the body and add the Content Length Header to the transmitted message.  The Python example clearly show which parameters are headers ( not part of the body) and  which parameters are in the body.

Comment: @jdweng yes, the items in angled brackets <> are real values, I just didn't include them here because I didn't want to reveal any sensitive information. The `<confluence server>`, `<pageID>`, and `<basicAuth>` are all correct because I'm able to use the same values for other API calls, including GET, POST, PUT, etc. which are working, I just can't upload files

Comment: Attachments are MIME.  A MIME attachment is a new line starting with two dashes.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140).  Here is an example of a Powershell MIMe : https://cherwellsupport.com/WebHelp/csm/en/9.3/content/system_administration/rest_api/csm_rest_powershell_upload_attachment.html